# Django - Render HTTP before database connection

Tags: django

I have a serverless database cluster that spins down when it's out of use. Cold starts take a minute or so, during which django just waits and waits to send the http request object back.

Before I code something complicated, I'm looking for recommendations for an existing middleware/signal integration that would allow me to render an interim view while django attempts to get the database connection (for instance, if the database query takes longer than a second to complete, render to this view instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution:

- I reduced the RESTful gateway's query timeout to 3 seconds. At the end of timeout, I return a 504 Error with a nice message that tells the user that the server has gone to sleep but it will be booting back up shortly. Inside the text/html response of the 504 Error, I included a refresh meta tag, so browsers will automatically try to reload the view.
- I took all database calls off the public-facing site and put them behind an authentication layer. This means that authenticating will be the step most likely to time out, and users will (I hope) naturally try to reauthenticate after receiving the 504 Error above.
- I added an AJAX jquery call in document.ready() to pull a random database record. This query will time out and nothing will happen (as intended). It forces the database server to begin booting up immediately whenever a user hits a public-facing page.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom middleware that tests for DB connectivity on every request. Bear in mind that this will attempt to create a new DB connection on every request

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def db_is_up_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        try:
            c = connection.cursor()
        except OperationalError:
            return render_to_response('your_template.html')
        else:
            return get_response(request)

    return middleware
```

Comment: Won't Django only throw the OperationalError after a failed connection? I'm not sure the connection is failing (it's coming from AWS), I think it's just saying "Okay, we see your connection, please wait."

Comment: Do you get a specific error when the connection fails?

Comment: Well, I get an unrelated error when the connection takes longer than 30s (http endpoint timeout), which is not enough time to spin up from the cold start. I don't believe the connection actually fails, as I haven't seen anything to that effect in the logs; I just need to render something to http in under 30 seconds - preferably sooner for a better user experience - so that I can use ajax to watch for the full app to be online and live.

Comment: Fairly certain it's the database cold boot that's the issue, and not the django/lambda cold boot, as I get the same laggy connection when I try to connect to a cold database from sql, but django itself spins up fairly rapidly when its view doesn't query the database at all.

Comment: Do you have a way of detecting if the database is available or not? Why are you stopping/starting the DB, is the application a POC?

Comment: I can detect if the database is currently up or down inside a view without attempting a db connection; however, if I make a connection to the database before I return render, that's still a blocking database call and the issue persists; after I return render, I can't call the database since I've already returned. I think this lambda+aurora stack is the most popular fully serverless django solution, and I think solving this issue elegantly would help a lot of people. A search for the error message I encountered was just a bunch of "Sorry, you can't do that," and I beg to differ :)

Comment: Interrupting the requested view's execution, sending a "please wait", connecting to the database to force it to boot, and then delivering the originally requested view -- much like how Cloudflare interrupts a DNS query to prevent DDoS attacks -- fixes this outright. That's what I hope to achieve.

Comment: Another option is using the CONN_MAX_AGE variable, set to the persistence timer of the database. Just need a way to check in middleware if we've exceeded CONN_MAX_AGE and then do a threaded, non-blocking db call.